# OpenSubtitles API search not responding with a value

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, promise, electron

I am trying to use the OpenSubtitles API NPM package in my electron App.

OpenSubtitles API
https://github.com/vankasteelj/opensubtitles-api

When i run this command to search for subtitles for a specified movie using its IMDB id and then sorting the results for a specific language etc:

```js
    const OpenSubtitlesApi = require('opensubtitles-api');
    const OpenSubtitles = new OpenSubtitlesApi({
        useragent:'UserAgent',
        username: 'username',
        password: 'password1',
        ssl: true
    });

    OpenSubtitles.search({
        sublanguageid: 'eng',
        extensions: ['srt', 'vtt'],
        imdbid: "tt0322259",
        limit: 3
    }).then(res => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    );
```

It should respond with an object / array like this:

```js
{
    0:
        date: "2011-05-15 13:19:33"
        downloads: 54215
        encoding: "CP850"
        filename: "The.Fast.And.The.Furious.II.2003.BluRay.720p.x264.DTS-WiKi.eng.srt"
        format: "srt"
        fps: 23.976
        id: "1952859375"
        lang: "English"
        langcode: "en"
        score: 0.5
        url: "https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/src-api/vrf-19dd0c5f/sid-3DRrLRTBf9EAZEfRVAnmx,rlso0/filead/1952859375"
        utf8: "https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subencoding-utf8/src-api/vrf-19dd0c5f/sid-3DRrLRTBf9EAZEfRVAnmx,rlso0/filead/1952859375"
        vtt: "https://dl.opensubtitles.org/en/download/subformat-vtt/src-api/vrf-19dd0c5f/sid-3DRrLRTBf9EAZEfRVAnmx,rlso0/filead/1952859375"
}
```

But instead i get nothing. It doesnt error, otherwise the `catch()` would have caught it.

I have tried running the entire thing inside a `SetInterval(() => {}, 100);` where it will eventually return a response and then shortly error because i am spamming the openSubtitles servers.

The function is placed inside a `$(document).ready();` which should wait for the document to be loaded, before proceeding - and it is also placed inside a `setTimeout(() => {}, 5000);` function to make sure the document is finished loading.

I have a suspiscion it is because it exists the `.then()` before it finishes and therefore it doesnt console.log(); the response it receieves? How do i test this further, or how do i stop it from exiting the then() if that is why this happens.

It might also be because it is thrown into a queue and not ended correctly, because when i paste the exact same function to call `OpenSubtitles.Search()` and paste it into the DevTools console, the response is the original call in the document.

Really hoping someone can help me out here :).

**Edit / Update:**

After further testing - I have found that if I run a `openSubtitles.search()` like the one above, nothing is returned.

*BUT* if I run another one just after the first one - a response is returned from the first time it ran.

**Example**: If I run this script:

```js
// First one  
    
console.log("Begin 1st");
      
OpenSubtitles.search({
    sublanguageid: 'eng',
    extensions: ['srt', 'vtt'],
    imdbid: "tt0322259",
    limit: 3
})
.then(res => {
    console.log("Response one");
});
    
// Second one
    
console.log("Begin 2nd");  
    
OpenSubtitles.search({
    sublanguageid: 'eng',
    extensions: ['srt', 'vtt'],
    imdbid: "tt0322259",
    limit: 3
})
.then(res => {
    console.log("Response two");
});

console.log("End");
```

The output will look like this:

```
Begin 1st
Begin 2nd
Response one
End
```

Even if I put the second `search();` inside a `setTimeout();`, to make sure the first gets time to complete, the output will look the same...

And just to be sure I tested the application on another machine, and the issue still persists. It was worth a try atleast.

Any advice / suggestions are *very* much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you add catch with a console log inside it?

Comment: For the lols - can you try adding a `setInterval(() => {})` to the top and seeing if it "makes it work"?  That would prove your assumption the issue is timing

Comment: When i add the .catch( err => { console.log(err) }) nothing happens - if i run the whole thing on an interval it doesn eventually return a response. Very weird.